# click-event doesn't fire if blur changes layout

Tags: javascript

I have a form with blur-events bound to the required fields. Then there is a "Cancel" Button which simply calls an URL (button is an image with click-event).

When leaving one of the required fields a warning is written to the page saying that field xy is required. -> this causes a layout shift, meaning all the fields and the buttons are moved down a little bit because of the text inserted above.

The tricky thing is this: when the focus is in an empty but required field and you click the cancel button, the required-warning is written to the screen but the click-event on the cancel button doesn't fire.
I think this is due to the layout shift. The mouse cursor doesn't hover over the button anymore, because the button scrolled down.

Has anyone a good idea how i could solve this?

Comment: same thing is happening to me on a Ruby on Rails project using jQuery, Formtastic and jQuery.Valtastic plugin

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt to display the warning before the change/blur events by polling a `setInterval` function, so that by the time you get to the ‘Cancel’ button the reflow has already occurred.

Or, you could catch `onmousedown` on the button instead of `onclick` as it will occur before blur. (Makes the button behave not-quite-as-expected though.)

But I'd probably simply try to make the warning not cause a reflow when it appears if possible, by leaving a blank space otherwise.